# opencv 3.0 Mat not provide a subscript operator

Tags: c++, opencv3.0, vlfeat

Im currently working on Opencv 3.0 C++ in Xcode 7.2. I have and code error written

```
Variable length array of non-POD element type cv::Mat
```

The sample code was define as below

```
Mat symbol[opts.numofblocksX*opts.numofblocksY];
```

I have change the code to

```
Mat symbol = symbol[opts.numofblocksX * opts.numofblocksY];
```

and it show another error

```
cv::Mat doest not provide a subscript operator
```

Is there anyone facing the same problem before? what was the solutions I can implement here?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to create an array of `Mat`, you can do: `std::vector<Mat> symbols(how_many);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
cv::Mat symbol[opts.numofblocksX*opts.numofblocksY];
```

Defines an array of `Mat`s of size `opts.numofblocksX*opts.numofblocksY`.

The error you got is because the size of this array is not fixed at compile time and this is not a [POD type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c).

Your new code is flawed.

```
cv::Mat symbol = symbol[opts.numofblocksX * opts.numofblocksY];
```

This defines a single `Mat` called symbol, and then nonsensically tries to call operator[] on it with `opts.numofblocksX * opts.numofblocksY` as an argument. This is not declaring an array.

Two obvious options present themselves:

- Allocate your array on the [heap](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/), where variable-size allocation is allowed. Don't forget to `delete[]` it later! (or use a smart pointer)

  `cv::Mat *symbol = new cv::Mat[opts.numofblocksX * opts.numofblocksY];`
- Use an std::vector (recommended):

  `std::vector<cv::Mat> symbols(opts.numofblocksX * opts.numofblocksY]);`